# Vestacp Iptables Firewall with geoip

Tags: firewall, iptables, vesta

I'm using Vesta Control Panel (vestacp) to control y VPS

I've installed Geoip to allow only some countries to access to the VPS

Everything is going well, when I type the command over SSH:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m geoip --src-cc CA -j ACCEPT
```

it works fine

the problem is:

- Vestacp does not keep this rule after restarting the firewall or the VPS even though I used iptables-persistent
- I can't add the rule using Vestacp UI because no ip used here
  Please let me know how to save this type of rules?
  Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `v-update-firewall` to update the Vesta firewall rules.

(Source: https://vestacp.com/docs/cli/)